# ItemAnimator animateChange oldHolder does not animate

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm using a ValueAnimator within `animateChange()` of my custom ItemAnimator to update the height of both the `newHolder` and `oldHolder` via setting `oldHolder.itemView.layoutParams` and `newHolder.itemView.layoutParams` with updated params.

The `newHolder`'s view animates correctly. The `oldHolder`'s view is stuck in a state where `isLayoutRequested() == true` and never redraws when its new layout parameters are set.

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
ValueAnimator.ofInt(INITIAL_HEIGHT, FINAL_HEIGHT).apply {
  duration = ANIMATION_DURATION

  addUpdateListener {  
    val newHeight = animatedValue as Int

    val oldLp = oldHolder.itemView.layoutParams
    oldLp.height = newHeight
    oldHolder.itemView.layoutParams = oldLp

    val newLp = newHolder.itemView.layoutParams
    newLp.height = newHeight
    newHolder.itemView.layoutParams = newLp
  }

  start()
}
```

I've left out some boilerplate for clarity. I extend DefaultItemAnimator and do dispatch change start/end in line with the animation beginning and ending.